# Python, Selenium Webdriver: Spans are not loaded for Firefox driver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I have a problem with Firefox driver to display spans for one of the popups of my site. 
I am not allowed to post images because of the reputation but here is the example how it looks like for Firefox and Chrome drivers:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6yzgi40xljpdyp5/spans.png

So for Firefox I need to modify my locator:

```
_apply_button = (By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Apply')]")
```

It does not work in this way for Chrome so there is another version for Chromedriver:

```
_apply_button = (By.XPATH, "//button[contains(span, 'Apply')]")
```

Is there a way to get the spans loaded properly?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Every Selenium question that gets a good answer includes the HTML text involved.  Screen captures are meaningless in this context, because they don't show the HTML structure against which the locators will be compared.

Comment: Are you saying that HTML is different for Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

Try to select the element [by link text](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html#locating-hyperlinks-by-link-text):

```
_apply_button = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Apply')
```

An other solution is the following:

```
_apply_button = (By.XPATH, "//button/span[contains(text(), 'Apply')]")
```

Comment: The problem is that these buttons are done in the following way: <button type="button" class="class"><span class="class">Apply</span></button>

Comment: Yes, I tryed to do that and it did not help. I need to figure out how to fix that in the way it is done, without id's.